# Does the following function have an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, random-variables, normal-distribution, time-series

Can the following function be integrated?

$X_t = c + \phi_1X_{t-1} + \phi_2X_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$

Where:

- $X_t$ is the variable of interest; $X_{t-1}$ is the value of $X_t$ at one time step earlier and $X_{t-2}$ is the value of $X_t$ at two time steps earlier
- $c$, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are some real numbers.
- $\epsilon$ is a random number from a normal distribution with a fixed mean and fixed standard deviation

Is the integral of $X_t$ defined? Is it possible to evaluate the integral of $X_t$? (I.e. the right hand side of the above equation)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this stuff, but is $\epsilon_t$ a continuous random variable or is it a huge pile of white noise?

Comment: Integral of $X_t$ with respect to what? An integral is a kind of sum of a *function* over a range of values of its variables. Are you wanting an integration with respect to $t$? But $t$ apparently takes on only discrete values (your "time steps"). "Integration" is a term we generally use for summing over a continuum. While it is true that the definition of integration can include discrete variables too, we usually just call that a sum, not an integration. So could you please be more specific about what you are attempting?